# unable to fetch some archives

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I have Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm trying to follow [Raspberry Pi Software Guide | Raspberry Pi Learning Resources](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/software-guide/update-sd-card/) and getting an error:

[image: unable to fetch some archives]

Comment: I've seen that happen time to time when some server misbehaves. try `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` as error message suggests. On some other occasions i have seen the problem go away if i simply wait for some time (hours ?) and retry

Comment: Ditto re, occasionally the servers go offline.  Not all that often and as Shreyas say they should come back after a while.  However, I don't know if the "mirror director" compensates, e.g., if it decides the most appropriate mirror for you is at the University of Atlantis and U of A is offline for a week...you'd hope it be smart enough to work around that, I always presume the problem is with the mirror director itself.  Also, I believe not all packages are hosted on all mirrors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @shreyas-murali, I tried again later (following day) and it's seems to be working now (or at least it's downloading & installing now). One would assume in case if server is down, mirrors were suppose to kick-in. I guess not...

Thanks anyways!